# .htaccess not behaving on all pages

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

The .htaccess file works correctly when I enter the homepage.  Then when I click through to another page I get this on the top and bottom of my page with some missing parts for that page:

> Authorization Required
>   This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
>   Additionally, a 401 Authorization Required error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What is the deal?  Additionally I told my browser to remember the password which might be causing the problem...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the page that you are going to is trying to pull in additional content from another directory that has a different authentication schema.  It could also be that the content is missing or trying to do a redirect which is throwing an error.  Log files would be helpful.

Comment: Log files just says '...file does not exist...'.  Chrome however says this: not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  Your hunch is correct.  I'm trying to pull something from secure.foo.com onto foo.com.  Never knew this was an issue.  Any insight would be helpful to accept your answer.

Comment: Are the page on secure.foo.com and foo.com in the same authentication realm, are they both using the same .htaccess file? Are they on the same server?  Does the file that you're trying to pull in actually exist?  Also, where does your ErrorDocument point to for 404s?  That should not require authentication.

Comment: Sorry to neglect all your follow up questions but my answer is yes.  My issue I believe originates from my ajax call to a login form displayed through facebox.  All of which is not a server specific issue.  I'll migrate to stackoverflow after some research.